# JSON Parse issue Classic ASP

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, asp-classic

I am retrieving a JSON Response from a remote server and the response comes back fine.

I am using a useful script I found http://www.violato.net/blog/others/89-using-classic-asp-library-to-parse-json-data for parsing the JSON data and extracting each value I need, just printing to screen at this stage.

If I copy paste the JSON response after some string manipulation directly into the JSON.parse() the code works great I get what I need. The problem comes when I pass the variable into JSON.parse() I get the error below. I have comment in my code to break it down.

If anyone can tell me where I am going wrong it would be great been trying so many variations but no luck. Thanks for looking.

```
<% @LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001" %>
<!--#include file="json2.asp"-->
<%

  url = "https://www.beds24.com/api/json/getBookings"
  propKey = Request.QueryString("propkey")

  jsonrequest = "{""authentication"": { ""apiKey"": ""XXXXXX"", ""propKey"": """&propKey&""" }, ""includeInvoice"": false, ""includeInfoItems"": false}"

'SEND JSON TO SERVER
 Dim oXMLHttp
 Set oXMLHttp=Server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
 oXMLHttp.open "POST", url,false
 oXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
 oXMLHttp.send jsonrequest

'GET JSON RESPONSE BACK FROM SERVER
    jsonstring = oXMLHttp.responseText

' HERE IS THE EXACT REPONSE FROM THE Server

response.write(jsonstring&"<br><br><br>")
'[{"bookId":"15536736","roomId":"220145","unitId":"1","roomQty":"1","status":"1","firstNight":"2019-11-25","lastNight":"2019-11-28","numAdult":"2","numChild":"0","guestTitle":"","guestFirstName":"","guestName":"","guestEmail":"","guestPhone":"","guestMobile":"","guestFax":"","guestCompany":"","guestAddress":"","guestCity":"","guestState":"","guestPostcode":"","guestCountry":"","guestCountry2":"","guestArrivalTime":"","guestVoucher":"","guestComments":"","notes":"","message":"","groupNote":"","custom1":"","custom2":"","custom3":"","custom4":"","custom5":"","custom6":"","custom7":"","custom8":"","custom9":"","custom10":"","flagColor":"","flagText":"","statusCode":"0","lang":"","price":"0.00","deposit":"0.00","tax":"0.00","commission":"0.00","currency":"USD","rateDescription":"","offerId":"0","referer":"Sergiowce","refererEditable":"Sergiowce","reference":"","apiSource":"0","apiReference":"","apiMessage":"","allowChannelUpdate":"1","allowAutoAction":"1","allowReview":"1","propId":"94848","ownerId":"52954","bookingTime":"2019-11-18 20:09:07","modified":"2019-11-18 20:09:07","masterId":""}]

' I THEN MANIPULATE THE SERVER REPONSE TO FORMAT IT READY FOR THE JSON.parse()
    jsonstring = replace(jsonstring,chr(34),chr(34)&chr(34))
    jsonstring = replace(jsonstring,"[","")
    jsonstring = replace(jsonstring,"]","")
    jsonstring = replace(jsonstring,"{","""{")
    jsonstring = replace(jsonstring,"}","}""")

' HERE IS THE EXACT TRANSFORMATION AFTER REPLACE HAS TAKEN PLACE

response.write(jsonstring&"<br/><br/>") 
'"{""bookId"":""15536736"",""roomId"":""220145"",""unitId"":""1"",""roomQty"":""1"",""status"":""1"",""firstNight"":""2019-11-25"",""lastNight"":""2019-11-28"",""numAdult"":""2"",""numChild"":""0"",""guestTitle"":"""",""guestFirstName"":"""",""guestName"":"""",""guestEmail"":"""",""guestPhone"":"""",""guestMobile"":"""",""guestFax"":"""",""guestCompany"":"""",""guestAddress"":"""",""guestCity"":"""",""guestState"":"""",""guestPostcode"":"""",""guestCountry"":"""",""guestCountry2"":"""",""guestArrivalTime"":"""",""guestVoucher"":"""",""guestComments"":"""",""notes"":"""",""message"":"""",""groupNote"":"""",""custom1"":"""",""custom2"":"""",""custom3"":"""",""custom4"":"""",""custom5"":"""",""custom6"":"""",""custom7"":"""",""custom8"":"""",""custom9"":"""",""custom10"":"""",""flagColor"":"""",""flagText"":"""",""statusCode"":""0"",""lang"":"""",""price"":""0.00"",""deposit"":""0.00"",""tax"":""0.00"",""commission"":""0.00"",""currency"":""USD"",""rateDescription"":"""",""offerId"":""0"",""referer"":""Sergiowce"",""refererEditable"":""Sergiowce"",""reference"":"""",""apiSource"":""0"",""apiReference"":"""",""apiMessage"":"""",""allowChannelUpdate"":""1"",""allowAutoAction"":""1"",""allowReview"":""1"",""propId"":""94848"",""ownerId"":""52954"",""bookingTime"":""2019-11-18 20:09:07"",""modified"":""2019-11-18 20:09:07"",""masterId"":""""}"  

'NOW COMES THE PROBLEM

'IF I USE THE FOLLOWING EVERYTHING WORKS PERFECTLY, HARD CODING THE MANIPULATED SERVER REPONSE INTO THE JSON.parse() AND I GET MY booking.bookId PRINTED TO SCREEN ----- bookId: 15536736

'Dim booking: set booking = JSON.parse("{""bookId"":""15536736"",""roomId"":""220145"",""unitId"":""1"",""roomQty"":""1"",""status"":""1"",""firstNight"":""2019-11-25"",""lastNight"":""2019-11-28"",""numAdult"":""2"",""numChild"":""0"",""guestTitle"":"""",""guestFirstName"":"""",""guestName"":"""",""guestEmail"":"""",""guestPhone"":"""",""guestMobile"":"""",""guestFax"":"""",""guestCompany"":"""",""guestAddress"":"""",""guestCity"":"""",""guestState"":"""",""guestPostcode"":"""",""guestCountry"":"""",""guestCountry2"":"""",""guestArrivalTime"":"""",""guestVoucher"":"""",""guestComments"":"""",""notes"":"""",""message"":"""",""groupNote"":"""",""custom1"":"""",""custom2"":"""",""custom3"":"""",""custom4"":"""",""custom5"":"""",""custom6"":"""",""custom7"":"""",""custom8"":"""",""custom9"":"""",""custom10"":"""",""flagColor"":"""",""flagText"":"""",""statusCode"":""0"",""lang"":"""",""price"":""0.00"",""deposit"":""0.00"",""tax"":""0.00"",""commission"":""0.00"",""currency"":""USD"",""rateDescription"":"""",""offerId"":""0"",""referer"":""Sergiowce"",""refererEditable"":""Sergiowce"",""reference"":"""",""apiSource"":""0"",""apiReference"":"""",""apiMessage"":"""",""allowChannelUpdate"":""1"",""allowAutoAction"":""1"",""allowReview"":""1"",""propId"":""94848"",""ownerId"":""52954"",""bookingTime"":""2019-11-18 20:09:07"",""modified"":""2019-11-18 20:09:07"",""masterId"":""""}")

'HERE IS THE PROBLEM LINE. IF I USE THE FOLLOWING I GET AN ERROR ALOUHGH IT IS THE SAME STRING AS ABOVE.

Dim booking: set booking = JSON.parse(jsonstring)

Response.Write("bookId: "& booking.bookId)   


Set booking = Nothing
%>
```

The error I get back in the browser.

Microsoft JScript compilation  error '800a03ee'

Expected ')'

/API/beds24/GetBookings/json2.asp, line 765

Here is json2.asp

```
<script language="Javascript" runat="server">

if(!Object.prototype.get) {
    Object.prototype.get = function(k) {
        return this[k];
    }
}

if(!Object.prototype.set) {
    Object.prototype.set = function(k,v) {
        if(typeof(v) == "unknown") {
            try {
                v = (new VBArray(v)).toArray();
            } catch(e) {
                return;
            }
        }
        this[k] = v;
    }
}

if(!Object.prototype["delete"]) {
    Object.prototype["delete"] = function(k) {
        delete this[k];
    }
}

if(!Object.prototype.keys) {
    Object.prototype.keys = function() {
        var d = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.Dictionary");
        for(var key in this) {
            if(this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                d.add(key, null);
            }
        }
        return d.keys();
    }
}

if(!String.prototype.sanitize) {
    String.prototype.sanitize = function(a, b) {
        var len = a.length,
            s = this;
        if(len !== b.length) throw new TypeError('Invalid procedure call. Both arrays should have the same size.');
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var re = new RegExp(a[i],'g');
            s = s.replace(re, b[i]);
        }
        return s;
    }
}

if(!String.prototype.substitute) {
    String.prototype.substitute = function(object, regexp){
        return this.replace(regexp || (/\\?\{([^{}]+)\}/g), function(match, name){
            if (match.charAt(0) == '\\') return match.slice(1);
            return (object[name] != undefined) ? object[name] : '';
        });
    }
}



// Create a JSON object only if one does not already exist. We create the
// methods in a closure to avoid creating global variables.

if (!this.JSON) {
    JSON = {};
}

(function () {

    function f(n) {
        // Format integers to have at least two digits.
        return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n;
    }

    if (typeof Date.prototype.toJSON !== 'function') {

        Date.prototype.toJSON = function (key) {

            return isFinite(this.valueOf()) ?
                   this.getUTCFullYear()   + '-' +
                 f(this.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' +
                 f(this.getUTCDate())      + 'T' +
                 f(this.getUTCHours())     + ':' +
                 f(this.getUTCMinutes())   + ':' +
                 f(this.getUTCSeconds())   + 'Z' : null;
        };

        String.prototype.toJSON =
        Number.prototype.toJSON =
        Boolean.prototype.toJSON = function (key) {
            return this.valueOf();
        };
    }

    var cx = /[\u0000\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g,
        escapable = /[\\\"\x00-\x1f\x7f-\x9f\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g,
        gap,
        indent,
        meta = {    // table of character substitutions
            '\b': '\\b',
            '\t': '\\t',
            '\n': '\\n',
            '\f': '\\f',
            '\r': '\\r',
            '"' : '\\"',
            '\\': '\\\\'
        },
        rep;


    function quote(string) {

// If the string contains no control characters, no quote characters, and no
// backslash characters, then we can safely slap some quotes around it.
// Otherwise we must also replace the offending characters with safe escape
// sequences.

        escapable.lastIndex = 0;
        return escapable.test(string) ?
            '"' + string.replace(escapable, function (a) {
                var c = meta[a];
                return typeof c === 'string' ? c :
                    '\\u' + ('0000' + a.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4);
            }) + '"' :
            '"' + string + '"';
    }


    function str(key, holder) {

// Produce a string from holder[key].

        var i,          // The loop counter.
            k,          // The member key.
            v,          // The member value.
            length,
            mind = gap,
            partial,
            value = holder[key];

// If the value has a toJSON method, call it to obtain a replacement value.

        if (value && typeof value === 'object' &&
                typeof value.toJSON === 'function') {
            value = value.toJSON(key);
        }

// If we were called with a replacer function, then call the replacer to
// obtain a replacement value.

        if (typeof rep === 'function') {
            value = rep.call(holder, key, value);
        }

// What happens next depends on the value's type.

        switch (typeof value) {
        case 'string':
            return quote(value);

        case 'number':

// JSON numbers must be finite. Encode non-finite numbers as null.

            return isFinite(value) ? String(value) : 'null';

        case 'boolean':
        case 'null':

// If the value is a boolean or null, convert it to a string. Note:
// typeof null does not produce 'null'. The case is included here in
// the remote chance that this gets fixed someday.

            return String(value);

// If the type is 'object', we might be dealing with an object or an array or
// null.

        case 'object':

// Due to a specification blunder in ECMAScript, typeof null is 'object',
// so watch out for that case.

            if (!value) {
                return 'null';
            }

// Make an array to hold the partial results of stringifying this object value.

            gap += indent;
            partial = [];

// Is the value an array?

            if (Object.prototype.toString.apply(value) === '[object Array]') {

// The value is an array. Stringify every element. Use null as a placeholder
// for non-JSON values.

                length = value.length;
                for (i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
                    partial[i] = str(i, value) || 'null';
                }

// Join all of the elements together, separated with commas, and wrap them in
// brackets.

                v = partial.length === 0 ? '[]' :
                    gap ? '[\n' + gap +
                            partial.join(',\n' + gap) + '\n' +
                                mind + ']' :
                          '[' + partial.join(',') + ']';
                gap = mind;
                return v;
            }

// If the replacer is an array, use it to select the members to be stringified.

            if (rep && typeof rep === 'object') {
                length = rep.length;
                for (i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
                    k = rep[i];
                    if (typeof k === 'string') {
                        v = str(k, value);
                        if (v) {
                            partial.push(quote(k) + (gap ? ': ' : ':') + v);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {

// Otherwise, iterate through all of the keys in the object.

                for (k in value) {
                    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(value, k)) {
                        v = str(k, value);
                        if (v) {
                            partial.push(quote(k) + (gap ? ': ' : ':') + v);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

// Join all of the member texts together, separated with commas,
// and wrap them in braces.

            v = partial.length === 0 ? '{}' :
                gap ? '{\n' + gap + partial.join(',\n' + gap) + '\n' +
                        mind + '}' : '{' + partial.join(',') + '}';
            gap = mind;
            return v;
        }
    }

// If the JSON object does not yet have a stringify method, give it one.

    if (typeof JSON.stringify !== 'function') {
        JSON.stringify = function (value, replacer, space) {

// The stringify method takes a value and an optional replacer, and an optional
// space parameter, and returns a JSON text. The replacer can be a function
// that can replace values, or an array of strings that will select the keys.
// A default replacer method can be provided. Use of the space parameter can
// produce text that is more easily readable.

            var i;
            gap = '';
            indent = '';

// If the space parameter is a number, make an indent string containing that
// many spaces.

            if (typeof space === 'number') {
                for (i = 0; i < space; i += 1) {
                    indent += ' ';
                }

// If the space parameter is a string, it will be used as the indent string.

            } else if (typeof space === 'string') {
                indent = space;
            }

// If there is a replacer, it must be a function or an array.
// Otherwise, throw an error.

            rep = replacer;
            if (replacer && typeof replacer !== 'function' &&
                    (typeof replacer !== 'object' ||
                     typeof replacer.length !== 'number')) {
                throw new Error('JSON.stringify');
            }

// Make a fake root object containing our value under the key of ''.
// Return the result of stringifying the value.

            return str('', {'': value});
        };
    }


// If the JSON object does not yet have a parse method, give it one.

    if (typeof JSON.parse !== 'function') {
        JSON.parse = function (text, reviver) {

// The parse method takes a text and an optional reviver function, and returns
// a JavaScript value if the text is a valid JSON text.

            var j;

            function walk(holder, key) {

// The walk method is used to recursively walk the resulting structure so
// that modifications can be made.

                var k, v, value = holder[key];
                if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
                    for (k in value) {
                        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(value, k)) {
                            v = walk(value, k);
                            if (v !== undefined) {
                                value[k] = v;
                            } else {
                                delete value[k];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return reviver.call(holder, key, value);
            }


// Parsing happens in four stages. In the first stage, we replace certain
// Unicode characters with escape sequences. JavaScript handles many characters
// incorrectly, either silently deleting them, or treating them as line endings.

            text = String(text);
            cx.lastIndex = 0;
            if (cx.test(text)) {
                text = text.replace(cx, function (a) {
                    return '\\u' +
                        ('0000' + a.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4);
                });
            }

// In the second stage, we run the text against regular expressions that look
// for non-JSON patterns. We are especially concerned with '()' and 'new'
// because they can cause invocation, and '=' because it can cause mutation.
// But just to be safe, we want to reject all unexpected forms.

// We split the second stage into 4 regexp operations in order to work around
// crippling inefficiencies in IE's and Safari's regexp engines. First we
// replace the JSON backslash pairs with '@' (a non-JSON character). Second, we
// replace all simple value tokens with ']' characters. Third, we delete all
// open brackets that follow a colon or comma or that begin the text. Finally,
// we look to see that the remaining characters are only whitespace or ']' or
// ',' or ':' or '{' or '}'. If that is so, then the text is safe for eval.

            if (/^[\],:{}\s]*$/.
test(text.replace(/\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g, '@').
replace(/"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g, ']').
replace(/(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g, ''))) {

// In the third stage we use the eval function to compile the text into a
// JavaScript structure. The '{' operator is subject to a syntactic ambiguity
// in JavaScript: it can begin a block or an object literal. We wrap the text
// in parens to eliminate the ambiguity.

                j = eval('(' + text + ')');

// In the optional fourth stage, we recursively walk the new structure, passing
// each name/value pair to a reviver function for possible transformation.

                return typeof reviver === 'function' ?
                    walk({'': j}, '') : j;
            }

// If the text is not JSON parseable, then a SyntaxError is thrown.

            throw new SyntaxError('JSON.parse');
        };
    }
}());










(function(){

    function __sanitize(value) {
        return value.sanitize(
            ['&',    '<',   '>',    '\'',    '"'],
            ['&amp;','&lt;','&gt;', '&apos;','&quot;']
        );
    };

    function __toXML(o, t) {
        var xml = [];
        switch( typeof o ) {
            case "object":
                if(Object.prototype.toString.apply(o) === '[object Array]') {
                    var a = o;
                    if(a.length === 0) {
                        xml.push("<{tag}/>".substitute({"tag":t}));
                    } else {
                        for(var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++) {
                            xml.push(__toXML(a[i], t));
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    xml.push("<{tag}".substitute({"tag":t}));
                    var childs = [];
                    for(var p in o) {
                        if(o.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                            if(p.charAt(0) === "@") xml.push(" {param}='{content}'".substitute({"param":p.substr(1), "content":__sanitize(o[p].toString())}));
                            else childs.push(p);
                        }
                    }
                    if(childs.length === 0) {
                        xml.push("/>");
                    } else {
                        xml.push(">");
                        for(var i = 0, len = childs.length; i < len; i++) {
                            if(p === "#text") { xml.push(__sanitize(o[childs[i]])); }
                            else if(p === "#cdata") { xml.push("<![CDATA[{code}]]>".substitute({"code": o[childs[i]].toString()})); }
                            else if(p.charAt(0) !== "@") { xml.push(__toXML(o[childs[i]], childs[i])); }
                        }
                        xml.push("</{tag}>".substitute({"tag":t}));
                    }
                }
                break;

            default:
                var s = o.toString();
                if(s.length === 0) {
                    xml.push("<{tag}/>".substitute({"tag":t}));
                } else {
                    xml.push("<{tag}>{value}</{tag}>".substitute({"tag":t, "value":__sanitize(s)}));
                }
        }
        return xml.join('');
    }

    if (typeof JSON.toXML !== 'function') {
        JSON.toXML = function(json, container){
            //container = container || "";
            var xml = [];
            if(container) xml.push("<{tag}>".substitute({"tag":container}));
            for(var p in json) {
                if(json.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                    xml.push(__toXML(json[p], p));
                }
            }
            if(container) xml.push("</{tag}>".substitute({"tag":container}));
            return xml.join('');
        }
    }

})();
</script>
```

Comment: You could use the server response as is, without manipulations. The following should work, commenting out all the `replace` lines in your code: please don't ask why/how :). I really dont know enough to explain. `for each bkg in booking : if bkg.get("roomId")<>"" Then : Response.Write("roomId: "& bkg.get("roomId") & "<br>"): end if : next` [You can replace the `:` in the code with newlines, used it here as multiline code is not really supported in comments]

Comment: Also, please add the `asp-classic` tag to question as it is related.

Comment: Thanks @SearchAndResQ I added the asp-classic and your advise worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been resolved in a comment by @SearchAndResQ (Thank you).

You could use the server response as is, without manipulations. The following should work, commenting out all the replace lines in your code:

```
for each bkg in booking : if bkg.get("roomId")<>"" Then : Response.Write("roomId: "& bkg.get("roomId") & "<br>"): end if : next
```

[You can replace the : in the code with newlines, used it here as multiline code is not really supported in comments] – SearchAndResQ

Comment: If you need to see all the keys and values, `for each bkg in booking : for each key in bkg.enumerate() : Response.Write(key & ": ") : if bkg.get(key)<>"" Then : Response.Write( bkg.get(key)): end if: Response.Write("<br>"): next: next`

Comment: @SearchAndResQ Thanks for that very useful. I have applied your logic and that works for one JSON request but applied to another type of request your solution returns an error. Not sure if I should create a new post or not as it is related to this question.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ I'll add the error but you might need more info. Microsoft VBScript runtime  error '800a01b6' Object doesn't support this property or method. The error line is 'for each bkg in booking'. This does not cause an error on another request. Let me know if I need to create new post. I'm new to JSON lots of learning to do!

Comment: That line could raise an error if the response is not a json array as  in your current example. Simply put, a Jason array is enclosed within square brackets as in your current response.  If it is not an array, you will need to comment out the first for each, and use booking instead of bkg.  Need to see the the other json if that does not work. Will check back tomorrow.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ You are right no array. I did as suggested and can get the checkIn to numAdult returned but I can't get roomId, propid, roomsavail etc. Do I need to loop through these maybe? Your input would be appreciated.{"checkIn":"20191121","lastNight":"20191126","checkOut":"20191127","ownerId":51766,"numAdult":2,"207022":{"roomId":"207022","propId":"90033","roomsavail":3,"price":1500,"priceFormated":"\u20ac1500"},"208667":{"roomId":"208667","propId":"90033","roomsavail":1},"208668":{"roomId":"208668","propId":"90033","roomsavail":1}}}

Comment: To add to my comment above. The returned results will show multiple responses like this format {"roomId":"****","propId":"*****","roomsavail":****}  due to the results showing available properties/rooms within the checkin/checkout dates.

Comment: Please edit your question, and add the new json formats that can be expected. Otherwise the information is all over the place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202845/discussion-between-searchandresq-and-scw).